# What's this 3D game?

Tags: identify-this-game

It was a 16 square playing board.  Each piece was a clear rectangle 1 wide, 2 tall.  Each piece had a red and yellow ball in the center encased in a transparent box.  The object was to get 4 in a row.  Everytime you played a piece, you also laid one down for your opponent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a [Cube Fusion](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/615/cube-fusion) variant.

> The game includes a playing board with a 5x5 grid and 12 playing pieces. Each piece consists of two cubes, each with marbles in the center - one red, one green. Players take turns placing pieces on the board, trying to make a specified pattern in his color but not his opponent's -- all the while having to play both his color and his opponent's color each turn. There are several different games explained in the rules: make 3, 4, or 5 in a row (in 3D) before your opponent, form a square in your color, form more three-in-a-row alignments than your opponent, etc.

As far as I know the board is 5x5, although there are rules for 4x4. Picture is of Double Decker, one of the repackagings of this game:

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  I've been searching everywhere to purchase this game.  It wasn't the full 5x5 grid, but that adds an extra dimension of challenge.